# How to set a class function to behave as another class function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have two classes, `ClassWorking` and `TemplateClass`, they are not related in any way.
Is there a way to say, I want the function `TemplateGenerate()` from my `TemplateClass` now to behave like the function `generate()` from my class `ClassWorking`.

Like a (this function does not exist) `SetFunctionBehavior(&templateClassRef->templateGenerate, &classWorkingRef->generate)`

I know I can use function pointer to make `TemplateClass` receive a pointer and call it in the class, but that not what I want.

It's more something like a `LD_Preload`, to replace the inner of function without having to re-write it and without inherit from a class who has it.

---

to be a little more explicit let's see it more like a node construction for class

`TemplateClass` can have multiple functions but not with the same behaviour

```
 - TemplateClass
   - TemplateGenerate() {will do this}
   - TemplateGenerate() {will do that}
   - TemplateGenerate() {will do like that}
```

and when I declare my class pointer `templateClassRef->TemplateGenerate = TemplateGenerate() {will do that}`

but not with a lambda :)

---

The point is to have something really generic without having to re-create a class for each need, for example I could have a class:

```
TemplateGenerate 
 - function A {A1 Behavior}  Functiun B {B1 Behavoir}  Functiun C {C1 Behavior}
              {A2 Behavior}             {B2 Behavoir}             {C2 Behavior}
              {A3 Behavior}             {B3 Behavoir}             {C3 Behavior}
```

And when I declare my function I say I take  A1,B2,C3 or A1,B1,C2

Comment: Is `generate` a static method, or does it need the object?

Comment: it need the object :)

Comment: I think you need to clarify. I fail to understand why inheritance is not what you are looking for. Try and post a full [MCVE] - showing an exact use case, where you copy-pasted the function, and what you wanted to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ClassWorking::generate` is a function that takes a `ClassWorking` and does stuff.

A function that has the same behaviour also takes a `ClassWorking`.  That is part of what the function does.

As `TemplateClass` is unrelated to `ClassWorking`, a method `TemplateClass::templateGenerate` that "behaves alike" `ClassWorking::generate` cannot succeed; you don't have a `ClassWorking`, so one of the prequisites of `ClassWorking::generate` isn't being fullfilled.

Now, it might be the case that the implementation of `ClassWorking::generate` *doesn't actually need* an instance of `ClassWorking`.  It might need something else.

But for the compiler to know this, you **have to change** the method from being a method of `ClassWorking` to being something else.  For example, you could write a free function `generate` that takes an argument what you *actually* need, and have `ClassWorking::generate` call that free function.

Then calling the free function `generate` from a stub method `TemplateClass::templateGenerate` becomes trivial.

C++ does not support "do what I mean" or "read my mind".  You actually have to tell the compiler what you want to happen.  And types matter in C++, so you cannot wire up a method on one class to another class without also telling C++ how the types relate.

There are languages where types are looser and you actually can grab a method off one class and glue it onto another.  These are generally interpreted languages with much heavier runtime object models than C++; members in this language are implemented as property bags of named values, values are actually variants at runtime, etc.

You can implement that kind of object in C++, but it isn't a "native" C++ object, and you'll have to write a pile of glue code (some of which could be hidden by metaprogramming).  That is far from a beginner task, and usually a bad idea; if you need the flexibility of scripting languages, just use a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use *composition*. Define an interface

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void/*maybe*/ templateGenerate(/*maybe*/) /*const?*/ = 0;
};
```

Then implement

```
struct ClassWorkingImpl : Interface, ClassWorking
{
    // ToDo - delegate all the constructors
    // ToDo - implement templateGenerate using the method in ClassWorking
};
```

and similarly for `TemplateClass`.

Then you instantiate `ClassWorkingImpl` &c. rather than `ClassWorking`. And you can call the interface method `templateGenerate` on either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with this method il will not be able to have different behavior for my templateGenerate without having to rewrite it. and my class classworking can't herit from Interface